# Inno Setup - setting file permission for QuickTime

Tags: inno-setup, file-association

I am trying to make ".mov" files associate with the QuickTime Player on Windows, as it seems by default, the Windows Media Player is trying to open them. I must not have something right in my iss file. Here is what I have:

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".mov"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "QuickTime.mov"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "QuickTimeFile"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "QuickTime File"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "QuickTime\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\QuickTimePlayer.exe,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "QuickTimeFile\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\QuickTimePlayer.exe"" ""%1"""
```

I also have ChangeAssociations=yes in the code at the top.

I must not have the correct value somewhere. After running the install it doesn't change the file association from Windows Media to QuickTime.

Comment: Shouldn;t this be an option in quicktime itself? Not an installer for an unrelated application. ESPECIALLY as you're doing it unconditionally!

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does not work! If the default value of `HKCR\.mov` is `QuickTime.mov`, then you need to write your settings to `HKCR\QuickTime.mov`!

```
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".mov"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "QuickTime.mov"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "QuickTime.mov"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "QuickTime File"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "QuickTime.mov\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\QuickTimePlayer.exe,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "QuickTime.mov\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\QuickTimePlayer.exe"" ""%1"""
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. which line(s) should I change, and what should it look like?

Comment: The `QuickTimeFile` and `QuickTime` subkeys should be replaced by `QuickTime.mov`. The first line tells Windows to look for settings in the `QuickTime.mov` subkey. Hence, you need to place your settings there!

Comment: By the way, I did post a corrected version of your snippet... That is how it should look like.

Comment: my apologies. i thought it was just a copy of what I posted. thank you for the help!

Comment: @Patric: It definitely should work. Are you sure that `QuickTimePlayer.exe` is really found at `{app}\QuickTimePlayer.exe`? (`{app}` expands to the directory (normally Program Files entry) of your own application, the one that is being installed.)

Comment: Yes it is indeed in the same directory as my app. But perhaps it should be {app}\QuicktTime\QuickTimePlayer.exe (note the folder name). I'll give that a try.

Comment: No luck with using the QuickTime folder either, alas. Still launching .mov files with WM Player. Shouldn't the installer ask me if I want to allow it to change from one association to the other? It never does that during the install process.

Comment: @Patric: No, since *you* are programming the installer, and so, if *you* haven't manually added such functionality, then such functionality will not exist!

Comment: Anyhow, the code above *does* work. Try to do something else. For example, create a new file association `.somenewext` that will open in `C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe`, and you'll see it works.

Comment: The new file assn didn't work either. The path to my QT Player is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QuickTimePlayer.exe" and my app is getting installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\" in its own folder, so is {app} the correct thing to put in front of "\QuickTimePlayer.exe"?

Comment: No, that means that `{app}` is wrong. If your application is installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp`, then this means that `{app}` is the same thing as `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp`. Thus, you are saying that the path to QuickTime.exe is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\QuickTimePlayer.exe`!

Comment: I thought so, but why doesn't it work if I put {pf} there instead? isn't that Program Files? I tried putting the direct path to QT as shown in my previous message, but that didn't work either. perhaps I've messed something up in regedit with one of my earlier tries? Sorry to be a pain, but this is all new to me.